# How to cntrol mouse pointer with Matlab or C?

Tags: c, matlab, image-processing, mouse, mousemove

I need to run a C or Matlab program at the bottom of windows running programs to move mouse, like using image processing to move mouse pointer.
how can i move mouse with a set of codes and how can i click right and left???

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Java Robot class directly from Matlab quite easily; something like:

```
robot = javaObjectEDT('java.awt.Robot');
robot.mouseMove(100, 200);
robot.mousePress(16);
robot.mouseRelease(16);
```

The parameters to mousePress and mouseRelease are constant values from InputEvent. You can find their values [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.event.InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK), and the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#mousePress%28int%29) tells you which constants to use (e.g. BUTTON1_MASK, or left-click, is 16).